# Crypto++ explicit destruction during encryption/decryption?

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I wrote some wrapper functions to encrypt/decrypt files using crypto++. I tried looking in the wiki but could find my answer. I am wondering if I need to explicitly destroy my objects that are created?

I found in the wiki that some objects when passed into functions are destroyed for you, but no examples of my exact use were there so I just wanted to be sure.

```cpp
   CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
   //Key generation
   byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
   prng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));
   //IV generation
   byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
   prng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));



   //print key
   encoded.clear();
   StringSource(key, sizeof(key), true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encoded)));
   cout << "key: " << encoded << endl;
   cout << "Size of key: " << sizeof(key) << endl;

   //print iv
   encoded.clear();
   StringSource(iv, sizeof(iv), true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encoded)));
   cout << "iv: " << encoded << endl;
   cout << "Size of iv: " << sizeof(iv) << endl;

   //See function below
   encrypt_file(inFile, outFile, key, iv, err); 

   inFile.close();
   outFile.close();
```

Once in this function the bytes arrays are truncated for some reason

### Encrypt_file

```cpp
    bool encrypt_file(std::ifstream& inFile,
       std::ofstream& outFile,
       const byte* key, const byte* iv,
       std::string& errMsg)
    {
       std::string encoded;
       //print key
       encoded.clear();
       StringSource(key, sizeof(key), true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encoded)));
       cout << "key: " << encoded << endl;
       cout << "Size of key: " << sizeof(key) << endl;

       //print iv
       encoded.clear();
       StringSource(iv, sizeof(iv), true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encoded)));
       cout << "iv: " << encoded << endl;
       cout << "Size of iv: " << sizeof(iv) << endl;
       try {
          CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption e;
          e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);
          CryptoPP::FileSource(inFile, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(e, new CryptoPP::FileSink(outFile)));
          inFile.close();
          outFile.close();
       }
       catch (CryptoPP::Exception& e) {
          errMsg = e.GetWhat();
          return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
```

### Output:

```
key: 6574D7BDFD0DD3BC59CD3846D4A196A8
Size of key: 16
iv: 1B4ED692F91A32246B41F63F6B8C6EAA
Size of iv: 16
key: 6574D7BDFD0DD3BC
Size of key: 8
iv: 1B4ED692F91A3224
Size of iv: 8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't. The objects you create have [*automatic storage duration*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), which means their destructor will be automatically invoked at the end of their scope. Moreover, the arguments that you pass with `new` will be owned by the Crypto++ objects, and their corresponding destructor will release the memory for you. They fall into the category of a *sink* or a *filter*, and it turns out that you also pass the ownership. For more details see:

https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining#Ownership

Basically this is what happens (super simplified example):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{};

class X
{
    Foo *p_;
public:
    X(Foo* p): p_(p) {}
    // we'd also need a copy ctor and copy assignment operator, ignored here
    ~X()
    {
        std::cout << "Releasing the memory...\n";
        delete p_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x(new Foo()); // sinking, no memory leak
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fe9aaf9e5366455)

I have to say that this is by far my least favourite style of software design. One can use templates and mixins to probably achieve similar things (read about [policy based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)), without pointers floating around with no clear ownership.

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thank you! Ya, i haven't encountered this type of design yet.

Comment: @hbchevelle68 This was a good question, I remember asking myself the exact same thing when I first bumped into Crypto++. I still think their design can be improved.

Comment: What would scale better a locally created object or a global one provided with thread synchronization? the local creation and destruction of the objects can be a performance hit because they allocate from the same heap.

Answer (score 4):

> I wrote some wrapper functions to encrypt/decrypt files using crypto++. I tried looking in the wiki but could find my answer. I am wondering if I need to explicitly destroy my objects that are created?

It depends. From the [README](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/Readme.txt#L92) under ***Important Usage Notes*** (the two items are listed):

> 1. If a constructor for A takes a pointer to an object B (except primitive types such as int and char), then A owns B and will delete B
>      at A's destruction.  If a constructor for A takes a reference to an
>      object B, then the caller retains ownership of B and should not
>      destroy it until A no longer needs it.
> 2. Crypto++ is thread safe at the class level. This means you can use Crypto++ safely in a multithreaded application, but you must provide
>      synchronization when multiple threads access a common Crypto++ object.

Here's your code. It looks good, and it will not need to be changed. But we can walk though it for completeness (the `CryptoPP` were removed for brevity):

```
FileSource(inFile, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor, new FileSink(outFile)));
```

1. you have the stack based `FileSource`. Its an automatic variable and it is deleted when it goes out of scope. Its boilerplate C++.
2. you have `inFile`. Its a reference, you are responsible for deleting it. Its stack based, and it is deleted when it goes out of scope in the caller. Its boilerplate C++.
3. you have the `StreamTransformationFilter` created with `new`. Its a pointer and the `FileSource` owns it. It will be deleted when the `FileSource` destructor runs. Pipelines are an acquired taste.
4. you have `encryptor`. Its a reference, you are responsible for deleting it. Its stack based, and it is deleted when it goes out of scope. Its boilerplate C++.
5. you have the `FileSink` created with `new`. Its a pointer and the `StreamTransformationFilter` owns it. It will be deleted when the `StreamTransformationFilter` destructor runs. Pipelines are an acquired taste.
6. you have `outFile`. Its a reference, you are responsible for deleting it. Its stack based, and it is deleted when it goes out of scope in the caller. Its boilerplate C++.

The information is on the wiki, but its kind of hard to find if you don't know what you are looking for. Also see [Pipelining | Ownership](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining#Ownership) on the wiki.

---

Related, this looks suspect:

```
e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);
```

Because `key` is a function parameter declared as `... byte key[], byte iv[] ...`, I believe it [decays to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/608639) with a size of 4 (i686) or 8 (x86_64). You should use something like the following, which allows you to specify the size of the array:

```
bool encrypt_file(std::ifstream& inFile,
    std::ofstream& outFile,
    const byte* key, size_t ksize,
    const byte* iv, size_t vsize,
    std::string& errMsg)
{
    ...
    e.SetKeyWithIV(key, ksize, iv);
    ...
}
```

So, given:

```
byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
prng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));
byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
prng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));
```

Then call it like so:

```
encrypt_file(inFile, outFile, key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv), err);
```

Comment: Wow i got 2 super awesome answers. The walk through helped make heads an tails of the whole thing, I really appreciated that. I went ahead and took your advice on the byte pointers, thanks for that catch!

Comment: Upon integrating the byte pointers i did a check to verify that the sizes, it is still getting degraded to size 8 (from 16). Any thoughts?

Comment: @hbchevelle68 - We need to see how you are calling `encrypt_file` and `decrypt_file`. If its a `SecByteBlock key`, just use `key, key.size()`. If its a `std::string key`, then use `reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(&key[0]), key.size()`.

Comment: I went ahead and edited to post to show how i call it as well as key gen and output.

Comment: You can call the functions with `key, sizeof(key)`. In the caller, `sizeof(key)` will be `AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH`. However, once in the called function, `byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH]` degrades to a pointer of size 4 (i686) or 8 (x86_64).

Comment: The term is ***decays***, not ***degrades***. Sorry about that. I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that! That was a lame mistake on my part